# How to simplify getting the last element of the recursion table

Tags: recursion

My code:

```
k = 2;
RecurrenceTable[{a[n + 1] == (-1)^(n + 1) b[n + 1] c[n + 1] + 3 (5 Q^4 - t) a[n], a[1] == -b[1] c[1] + 3 (5 Q^4 - t)^2, b[n + 1] == (b[n] c[n])/(Q (n + 1)), b[1] == 5 Q^(3 + 5 k), c[n + 1] == c[n] - 5, c[1] == 20 + 25 k}, {a, b, c}, {n, 1, 5}] // Last // First // Factor

(* Output:
-31281250 Q^9 + 46921875 Q^14 - 51187500 Q^19 + 42187500 Q^24 - 17718750 Q^29 - 9384375 Q^10 t + 20475000 Q^15 t - 27590625 Q^20 t + 14175000 Q^25 t - 2047500 Q^11 t^2 + 6885000 Q^16 t^2 - 4252500 Q^21 t^2 - 914625 Q^12 t^3 + 567000 Q^17 t^3 + 91125 Q^8 t^4 - 28350 Q^13 t^4 - 7290 Q^4 t^5 + 243 t^6
*)
```

I need to change $k$=`0..20` and $n$=`1..50`.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `Table[RecurrenceTable[...]//Last//First//Factor, {k, 0, 20}, {n, 50}]`? (Possibly with `Flatten[..., 1]` applied if you don't want lists of lists)

Comment: @thorimur, The problem is that already at n = 20 the calculations freeze.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

$Assumptions = k ∈ Integers && k >= 0 && n ∈ Integers && n > 0;

eqns = {a[n + 1] == (-1)^(n + 1) b[n + 1] c[n + 1] + 3 (5 Q^4 - t) a[n], 
   a[1] == -b[1] c[1] + 3 (5 Q^4 - t)^2, b[n + 1] == (b[n] c[n])/(Q (n + 1)), 
   b[1] == 5 Q^(3 + 5 k), c[n + 1] == c[n] - 5, c[1] == 20 + 25 k};

nmax = 7;
```

Generating a [`RecurrenceTable`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RecurrenceTable.html)

```
(tab = RecurrenceTable[eqns, {a, b, c}, {n, 1, nmax}] // FullSimplify);
```

Use [`FindSequenceFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindSequenceFunction.html) to find the closed-form expression for `b[n]` and `c[n]`

```
b[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[tab[[All, 2]], n]

(* -((5^n (-(1/Q))^n Q^(4 + 5 k) Pochhammer[-4 - 5 k, -1 + n])/
 Pochhammer[2, -1 + n]) *)

c[n_] = FindSequenceFunction[tab[[All, 3]], n]

(* 5 (5 + 5 k - n) *)
```

The equations then reduce to

```
eqns2 = (eqns // FullSimplify) /. True -> Nothing

(* {3 (5 Q^4 - t) a[n] + (
   5^(2 + n) (-4 - 5 k + n) Q^(3 + 5 k - n) Pochhammer[-4 - 5 k, n])/
   Pochhammer[2, n] == a[1 + n], 
 25 (4 + 5 k) Q^(3 + 5 k) + a[1] == 3 (-5 Q^4 + t)^2} *)
```

Using [`RSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) to solve for `a[n]`

```
a[k_, n_] = a[n] /. RSolve[eqns2, a[n], n][[1]] // FullSimplify

(* (3^(-4 - 5 k) (2 + n) Q^-n Gamma[
    2 + n] (-3125 3^(4 + 5 k) Q^(5 (4 + k)) (15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)^n + 
     3125 (15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)^n (3 Q + 5/(-5 Q^4 + t))^(5 k) - 
     37500 Q^5 (15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)^n (3 Q + 5/(-5 Q^4 + t))^(5 k) + 
     7500 Q t (15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)^n (3 Q + 5/(-5 Q^4 + t))^(5 k) - 
     67500 Q^6 t (15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)^n (3 Q + 5/(-5 Q^4 + t))^(5 k) + 
     202500 Q^11 t (15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)^n (3 Q + 5/(-5 Q^4 + t))^(5 k) - 
     202500 Q^16 t (15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)^n (3 Q + 5/(-5 Q^4 + t))^(5 k) + 
     6750 Q^2 t^2 (15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)^n (3 Q + 5/(-5 Q^4 + t))^(5 k) - 
     40500 Q^7 t^2 (15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)^n (3 Q + 5/(-5 Q^4 + t))^(5 k) + 
     60750 Q^12 t^2 (15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)^n (3 Q + 5/(-5 Q^4 + t))^(5 k) + 
     2700 Q^3 t^3 (15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)^n (3 Q + 5/(-5 Q^4 + t))^(5 k) - 
     8100 Q^8 t^3 (15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)^n (3 Q + 5/(-5 Q^4 + t))^(5 k) + 
     405 Q^4 t^4 (15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)^n (3 Q + 5/(-5 Q^4 + t))^(5 k) + 
     84375 Q^(5 (2 + k)) (2 - 4 Q^5 + 3 Q^10) (15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)^
      n (3 - 5/(5 Q^5 - Q t))^(5 k) + 
     3^(4 + 5 k + n) (5 Q^5 - Q t)^
      n ((5 Q^4 - t)^5 + 
        5 Q^(4 + 5 k) (10 Q^4 - t) t (50 Q^8 - 10 Q^4 t + t^2)) - ((-5)^(
        2 + n) 243^k (-5 - 5 k + n) Q^(
        5 k) (15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)^3 Gamma[5 + 5 k] Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[
         1, -4 - 5 k + n, 2 + n, 5/(15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)])/Gamma[5 + 5 k - n] + (
     1/(4 + 5 k - n))
     5^(2 + n) 243^k Q^(
      5 k) (15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)^3 Hypergeometric2F1Regularized[2, -4 - 5 k + n, 
       2 + n, 5/(15 Q^5 - 3 Q t)] Pochhammer[-4 - 5 k, 1 + n]))/((-5 Q^4 + 
     t)^4 Gamma[3 + n]) *)
```

Checking against your example,

```
Factor[a[2, 5]] == -31281250 Q^9 + 46921875 Q^14 - 51187500 Q^19 + 
  42187500 Q^24 - 17718750 Q^29 - 9384375 Q^10 t + 20475000 Q^15 t - 
  27590625 Q^20 t + 14175000 Q^25 t - 2047500 Q^11 t^2 + 6885000 Q^16 t^2 - 
  4252500 Q^21 t^2 - 914625 Q^12 t^3 + 567000 Q^17 t^3 + 91125 Q^8 t^4 - 
  28350 Q^13 t^4 - 7290 Q^4 t^5 + 243 t^6

(* True *)
```

The expressions get quite large

```
LeafCount@Factor[a[20, 50]]

(* 10120 *)
```